# cannot debug from Xcode after update

Tags: objective-c

I updated Xcode to 4.3.1 and cannot debug any more:

```
error: failed to launch 'someapp' -- failed to get the task for process 2851
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this happen on a prior version of xcode when i upgraded. What I had to do was create new my provisioning profiles for my app. Prior to this though I would check your provisioning profiles.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this many-a-times. I think what you need to is just clean your app (cmd+shift+k). Delete app from the device. Restart xcode and Run.

I think you might have tried this already, but this generally solves it for me.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the iOS Version of your device you may need to install debug support for those devices. 
In the top left of the screen, next to the run and stop icons, where you choose the target and the device/simulator, choose "more simulators". There you can install additional iOS version simulators and debug support for even older iOS versions.

If that does not work then try using the organizer window. Check whether the development profies are properly installed. Try deleting them and prepare your device (while it is connected) for debugging. (This will automatically request and install the development profile)

Comment: Well, yes, this may not match your specific situation. However, I observed quite similar error messages and several actions helped solving it, depending on the situation. It may be helpful for other readers though.